# How to return a new instance of `T` in an inline reified function?

Tags: kotlin, generics, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

I have the following code:

```
private inline fun <reified T : Number> T.test(): T {
    if (T::class.java == Double::class.java) {
        return 0.0
    }

    return this
}
```

I expected that that would work (as long as I checked the type of `T`), but the IDE points this out:

> The floating-point literal does not conform to the expected type `T`

[image]

Is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to cast it to T since the compiler isn't sophisticated enough to figure it out.

```
private inline fun <reified T : Number> T.test(): T {
    if (T::class == Double::class) {
        return 0.0 as T
    }

    return this
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply :). I was wondering if there is any way to do it without having to cast the value. I thought the smartcast would work.

Comment: There isn’t. The compiler isn’t sophisticated enough for this. Maybe someday it will be.